# how to set up one launch configuration for each / many projects in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

i'm using eclipse 2.02 Keppler edition to develop my software projects. But now i got a little thing to solve... At the moment we have a lot of projects, each is running its own launch configuration stored at

> \"workspace"\"projectname".settings\

. Every single launch config is equal to the other, now I want to set up only one config e.g. stored at

> \"workspace".metadata.plugins...somewhere there

, all my projects must use this central (default) launch config.
Is my plan possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible out of the box with Eclipse.

The only idea, I have is to write a small (shell-)script that generates all the launch configurations from the central template.

Comment: What a pity... Do you have much experiance with eclipse?

Comment: I think I can say that :-) - Your use case seems not very common according to my experience. Most people have workspaces with many projects which depend on each other and only have one or two (e.g., client/server) launch configuratons. Many small projects with similar launch configurations seems unusual to me.

Comment: Each developer, has only one workspace with many repositories of our projects in it.

Comment: Each developer, has only one workspace with many repositories of our projects in it. If a developer make a new project, and define e.g. a main class which shall be started, at first time pressing the RUN button in eclipse, it's asking to select "a way to run" (applet or application). All the same way I choose, eclipse is generating a new launch config for this project. I's not possible for me to set a pre-defined launch config for this project.